# How to Get Project details of employee using stuff function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my Query:

```
SELECT employeedetail.firstname
    ,(
        SELECT STUFF((
                    SELECT ',' + projectname
                    FROM productdetail
                    GROUP BY projectname
                    HAVING count(projectname) > 1
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                    ), 1, 1, '') AS abc
        FROM productdetail
        INNER JOIN employeedetail ON productdetail.employeeid = employeedetail.employeeid
        GROUP BY productdetail.projectname
        HAVING count(productdetail.projectname) > 1
        ) AS projects
    ,count(productdetail.projectname) AS number_of_projects
FROM employeedetail
INNER JOIN productdetail ON employeedetail.employeeid = productdetail.employeeid
GROUP BY employeedetail.firstname
HAVING count(productdetail.projectname) > 1
```

what I am going to do is, I want to select employee firstnames from employeedetail table who are working on more than one projects and based on their projectdetail.employeeid which is used as a foreign key on projectdetail table and concatenate their projectnames according to employeename

For example:

```
Adam      project1,project2,project3

jorge     project1, project2
```

my query is not giving me exact result what I want. Here is my Projectdetail table

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT employeedetail.employeeid
FROM employeedetail
INNER JOIN productdetail ON employeedetail.employeeid = productdetail.employeeid
GROUP BY employeedetail.employeeid
HAVING count(productdetail.projectname) > 1
)

SELECT C.employeeid, STUFF((SELECT ',' +P.projectname 
   FROM productdetail P 
   WHERE P.employeeid = C.employeeid FOR XML PATH('') ),1,1,'')
FROM CTE C
```

In this I have taken employee IDs into CTE, who are having multiple project and done with for XML..

**Edit:**

In your code there are unnecessary checks for `count>1` and one more thing is there is no join between Outer Select and Inner Select(used for Stuff). Since there is no Join between these selects the comma separated project list will append to each employee.

I have done the same thing but in a `WHERE` clause I joined Outer Select EmpID with Stuff select EMPID.

For simplification I have used CTE. You can do this as below

```
 SELECT employeedetail.employeeid
       ,employeedetail.firstname
       ,count(productdetail.projectname) Project_Count
       , STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + P.projectname
            FROM productdetail P
            WHERE P.employeeid = employeedetail.employeeid
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')

FROM employeedetail
INNER JOIN productdetail ON employeedetail.employeeid = productdetail.employeeid
GROUP BY employeedetail.employeeid,employeedetail.firstname
HAVING count(productdetail.projectname) > 1
```

Comment: It's Working but what is wrong with my code? I want to do it without using CTE

Comment: gIven explanation for your mistake in code. Check updated answer @JasonClark

Comment: it's working but what if I want to retrieve firstname as well? second, i am running following code: (SELECT STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + projectname
            FROM productdetail  WHERE productdetail.employeeid = employeedetail.employeeid
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '') as abc
FROM productdetail inner join employeedetail on productdetail.employeeid=employeedetail.employeeid 
group by employeedetail.firstname, employeedetail.employeeid having count(productdetail.projectname)>1)

Comment: which is giving me project detail separately in a subquery and for firstname i am using main query but when combining both it giving me error

Comment: If you want to display Firstname, Count values, you can.. But put firstname in group by.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133414/discussion-between-jason-clark-and-shakeer-mirza).

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

```
SELECT employeedetail.firstname
    ,(
        SELECT STUFF((
                    SELECT ',' + pd.projectname
                    FROM productdetail as pd
                    WHERE pd.employeeid = employeedetail.employeeid
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                    ), 1, 1, '')
       ) AS projects
    ,count(DISTINCT productdetail.projectname) AS number_of_projects
FROM employeedetail
INNER JOIN productdetail ON employeedetail.employeeid = productdetail.employeeid
GROUP BY employeedetail.firstname,number_of_projects
HAVING count(DISTINCT productdetail.projectname) > 1
```